# Copy Constructor Node class for a Singly Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor

Ok, so I'm writing a Node class that is a container for a type Element. I'm supposed to write a copy constructor to iterate through the links of Node classes and copy each node.

For the Node class, the only variables are an Element (the data contained) and a pointer to the next node, and if there is no next node it will point to nullptr.

I understand I need to make a 'deep' copy and make new nodes for each of the nodes pointed.

What I had was something like this:

```
    Node::Node(const Node& rhs)
    {
         ele(the element) = rhs.ele;
         next = rhs.next;
         Node cur = Node(ele);
         cur.next = next;
         while(cur.next != nullptr)
         {
              Node* n = new Node(cur.ele);
              (*n).next = cur.next;
              cur = *(cur.next);
         }
         return *this;
     }
```

Obviously this doesn't work at all. To my understanding, to keep the copies I need to store the new nodes on the heap and keep allocating new nodes until I hit the nullptr, but I'm not sure how exactly to implement this. Thank you!

Comment: Separate the classes for `Node` and `List` (your individual elements and the container of them).

Comment: You should use std::list or std::vector container classes. If you may want to see the source code of C++ STL and see how it has been implemented and how std::allocator has been used to do memory management.

Answer (score 0):

You mix up the notion of node with the notion of list. class node has not to have a copy constructor. It is class list that has to have a copy constructor.

If your list is just a pointer to a node that is to the head then you need to write a separate function that will clone an existent list.

For example the function could look the following way

```
Node * Clone( const Node *head )
{
   Node *new_head = nullptr;

   if ( head )
   {
      new_head = new Node { head->ele, nullptr };

      for ( Node *p1 = head, *p2 = new_head; p1->next; p1 = p1->next, p2 = p2->next )
      {
         p2->next = new Node { p1->next->ele, nullptr };
      }
   }

   return new_head;
}
```